# play-services-base versus -basement dependencies (AAR) in Android

Tags: android, maven, unity-game-engine, aar, prime31

I found an xml file GoogleDependencyFlurryPlugin.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency><groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId><artifactId>play-services-base</artifactId><version>8.4+</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId><artifactId>play-services-basement</artifactId><version>8.4+</version></dependency>
</dependencies>
```

and indeed an xml file GoogleDependencyPlayGameServicesPlugin.xml

```
<dependencies>
<dependency><groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId><artifactId>play-services-games</artifactId><version>8.4+</version></dependency>
<dependency><groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId><artifactId>play-services-plus</artifactId><version>8.4+</version></dependency>
</dependencies>
```

Now, at one point the former file had ***ONLY***

## play-services-base > OR < play-services-basement

and that seemed to cause a huge problem. *AndroidJavaException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:* once running on a device.

Android experts, is it the case that if you have "base" **you must have** "basement" ... or perhaps **vice versa**?

Indeed, WRT play-services-games or play-services-plus, perhaps one/both of those depend in some way (or contradict?) base/basement?

Comment: If you look in your app/build directory in Android Studio after compilation, you'll notice that `basement` has additional classes that `base` doesn't have.  I.e. it has **zze.class**, which `GooglePlayServicesUtil` extends from.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The library `play-services-basement` is a dependency of `play-services-base`. It was introduced in Google Play Service version 8.1.0 to help to reduce the size of some other libraries like `play-services-ads` and `play-services-analytics`.

When you add `play-services-base` you automatically add also `play-services-basement` so it's not necessary to add the explicit dependency.

You can check the dependencies of every single library in your local Google repository.

For example for the library `play-services-games` open the file pom file that is located here:

```
extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/play-services-games/8.4.0/play-services-games-8.4.0.pom
```

this is the content of the file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd" xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
  <artifactId>play-services-games</artifactId>
  <version>8.4.0</version>
  <packaging>aar</packaging>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-base</artifactId>
      <version>8.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.google.android.gms</groupId>
      <artifactId>play-services-drive</artifactId>
      <version>8.4.0</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
      <type>aar</type>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
</project>
```

As you can see `play-services-games` depends on `play-services-base` and `play-services-drive`

Comment: Thanks for this incredible answer!  So in fact, regarding the first file since it has `play-services-base`, actually there is no point adding `play-services-basement` - I've understood you correctly?  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you are right, there is no point in adding `play-services-basement` if you already add `play-services-base`.

Comment: got it, **thanks**.  for the other, since it uses play-services-games, do you mean I **must** include play-services-base and play-services-drive?  Or did I misunderstand you?   thanks...

Comment: You don't need to explicitly add `play-services-base` and `play-services-drive` because they are automatically added since they are the dependency of `play-services-games`

Comment: Why don't I see **play-services-base** listed here: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#split

Comment: The list identifies only the dependencies that map a public API. There are many different dependencies. You can see all the available dependencies in your local `Google repository` located here:  `<android-sdk>/extras/google/m2repository/com/google/android/gms/`

Comment: <rant>If you're Google and you already reached the `base`, you apparently only can go deeper by going to the `basement` :)</rant>